# Tikz: Crop the top of a tree. Snap the resuling bounding box to the tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  actor/.style={
    circle,
    draw,
    minimum size=10mm
  }
}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=20mm, level distance=20mm]
        \node[actor] {user}
        child[dashed] {node[actor,solid] {1}
                child[solid] {node[actor] {3}}
                child[solid] {node[actor] {4}}}
        child[dashed] {node[actor,solid] {2}};
        \draw[red] (current bounding box.north west) rectangle (current bounding box.south east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The above code produces the following image:

[image: Current]

Note that the red bounding box is perfectly snapped to the tree.

I want to crop out node "user" from the image, so that a small part of the edges is maintained.
It does not matter what technique is used (i.e., clip or bounding box).

The red lines represent the bounding box. They are not needed in the resulting image. They just show that, in the resulting image, the bounding box is perfectly snapped to the tree.

It's helpful to visualize the original image and the expected result, side by side, wrapping the tikz pictures in `fbox`:

[image: ![enter image description here]

There exists a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77195895/2777074) on StackOverflow. The question does not have the requirement of the bounding box being snapped to the tree. The answer applies clip at the top of the tikz picture:

```latex
\clip (-2.5,-4.5) rectangle (1.5,-1);
```

However, I am looking for a more programmatic solution, where I don't have to manually calculate some adequate numbers, which is prone to error.
For example, consider the following clip, where I exaggerate the error:

```latex
\clip (-2.3,-4.5) rectangle (1.5,-1);
```

If we highlight in the bounding box in red, we can see that it is incorrect:

[image]

I am looking for a solution that produces no gaps at all.

Comment: If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every question. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

Comment: x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/77195895/2777074

Comment: The solution you provided in the answer you cross posted does not achieve what I describe here, as the margins it produces are not properly aligned. Thanks for downvoting.

Comment: If you are looking for a specific solution, you should mention the requirements in the question. Also the downvote is for cross-posting without linking to other versions. This makes the post not useful.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. I think the image at the bottom of this post is enough self explicative. Anyways, I will edit right now the post at the best of my capabilities!

Comment: The picture can be achieved by using `\clip`. You should spell out your specific requirements if you are not satisfied with the obvious solution.

Comment: If your actual goal is to draw a zoomed in part of the tree next to it (as per comments to your duplicate question), you'd better ask about this instead because then one could show a solution using the spy library.

Comment: Do you want to crop the bounding box or do you want to clip your whole picture? These are two different things.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I am looking for whatever solution that produces the second image in the question (I don't know if this is done by clipping the image or reducing the bounding box). Note that the solution crossposted by the other user is not okay (I edited the post explaining why).

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I agree that I could have been more diligent, but you could have advised me on how to improve rather than immediately downvoting (implicitly discouraging me). Ultimately, I followed your suggestions: there is no point in immediately downvoting, as this creates a toxic and not welcoming community.

Comment: What creates a toxic atmosphere is to ask a question which shows as a goal an image with spaces around the tree https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QPT7.png and then criticize the solution for reproducing this design.

Comment: ... and neither this question nor the duplicate contain working links to one another, so they are not useful in their current form. Once both of them are edited, I would retract my vote.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Okay, sorry if there has been friction.

Comment: Please edit your SO post to include a working link to your duplicate

Comment: Asking useful questions can be hard. The best way to learn what a good question contains, is to answer a couple of questions first. While working on answers, you will realize, what information a question needs to contain.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have updated this post to the real best of my current capabilities, hopefully it should be all clear now.

Comment: I don't understand the requirements of this question and the link to SO is defunct, so no clues there. If you want a programmatic solution, what is the algorithm supposed to do exactly? Is it always the root of the tree which should be removed? Is the width of the root guaranteed to be less than the width of the tree? There are cases where removing a single node won't change the bounding box. Must the tree be drawn using this method (as opposed to `forest`, for example)? What should happen if the removed part includes a parent(s)? Should part of that edge be drawn? What's the input exactly?

Comment: BTW: The answer from which you got the code for the dashed lines from, was published under CC BY-SA 4.0, which means that you should mention the author with a link back to the answer

Comment: Although I don't understand this question as it stands, it does make a significant effort (e.g. it includes an MWE, which many questions don't, and images etc.). I don't think we should close it this quickly, but give the user time to clarify and improve it. I understand that some people commenting are annoyed, but many of us had little clue how the site worked or what the conventions were. I think that's colouring the close-votes here and I don't see it as constructive or welcoming.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

[image]

Code (sure not the better):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \tikzset{
        actor/.style={
            circle,
            draw,
            minimum size=10mm
        }
    }
    
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=20mm, level distance=20mm]
            %\clip(-4,2) -- (4,-1);
            \node[actor] {user}
            child[dashed] {node[actor,solid] {1}
                child[solid] {node[actor] {3}}
                child[solid] {node[actor] {4}}}
            child[dashed] {node[actor,solid] {2}};
            \draw[red] (current bounding box.north west) rectangle (current bounding box.south east);
            \fill[white] (current bounding box.north west) rectangle (3,-1);
            \draw[red] (-2.5,-1)--(1.5,-1);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: Add this line of code before `\end{tikzpicture}`

```
\draw (-2.8,-4.7) rectangle (1.8,-.8);
```

and You have the desired result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your attempt. Copying and pasting your solution, I see that it has some defects. https://imgur.com/a/NVvhzSK
It should result like this:
https://imgur.com/a/KifGcjD

Comment: again: you don't mention the requirements, like aligning it to other pictures, in your question. Is is very unfair to then criticize a working solution which reproduces what you asked for in the question.

Comment: My code anwers exactly to your question. If they a better code chapeau!

Comment: @RaffaeleSantoro Sorry for wasting your time, I have updated the question. Feel free to  remove it, as it does not implement what I need (my fault!).